# Inlining functions in Go

Tags: sorting, go

Go has a nice generic implementation of introsort using the generic `sort.Interface`. But one of the advantages of C++'s `std::sort` is that you can specify a compare functor which is inlined and unnecessary function calls are omitted.
Can we force the current native Go compilers somehow to inline those `sort.Swap` and `sort.Less` calls? I do not consider `gccgo` because it gives us terrible results compared to the native compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Go 1.x the answer is a sound no.

The Go compiler may inline some classes of functions on some platforms in some specific ways. You might even be able to figure out some trickery through which you can make the current compiler inline the sort-"functor" on your architecture but there is absolutely no guarantee whatsoever that this will hold in future releases and it may work against you (even break your code, depending on the level of hackery involved) when the compiler changes.

A major release of Go (2.x?) *might* provide some guarantees about optimizations; but for Go 1.x there's nothing like that. And even if the Go authors wanted to do this it's difficult to provide such guarantees for all platforms (remember Go runs on many architectures).

Even more generally it is a bad idea to rely on compiler-specific behavior, in any language.

Comment: Thank you. I absolutely do agree that relying on the specific compiler optimizations is a bad idea. But currently we have a "sort-intensive" module and it's a shame that Go is twice as slow as C++ just because this inlining thing. We've measured the version without `sort.Interface` and the difference is huge.

Comment: If sort-performance is critical you may well justify writing a more use-case specific and faster sort implementation; custom-made for your needs.

Comment: Are you sure the Swap and Less are not inlined? You can check it with `go build -gcflags='-m'` to see optimization decisions. Simple Less and Swap functions are usually inlined.